# IE7 position absolute with margin auto bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

i have problem with positioning and margin in IE7. I have got div with absolute position and auto margin.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
```

This div should be centered to its relative position parent. But in IE7 this is not working.  Here is example of working code http://jsfiddle.net/3zwkA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical centering in CSS is a PITA, especially when you also want IE7 (or even IE6) support. [There are many ways to do it](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/), but each come with some kind of drawback. Your method corresponds to method 4 in the linked article, and is known to malfunction in IE < 8.

For elements with fixed width and height though, a more robust method (method 2 in the article) consists of positioning it at `top: 50%; left: 50%` and subtracting half of the width from the top and left margins. This works in all browsers. [Here, have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/uBhGV/).

Comment: acctualy is not a vertical centering problem, but you are right. My problem is fixed with negative margin, but when i have non fixed width/height it's problem...

Comment: @Piklis I don't know of any solution for non-fixed sized elements with decent IE support. Either you fix the size or you drop IE support.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to center absolutely the div in it's parent you should do :

```
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    margin-top:-25px;
    border: 1px yellow solid;
}
```

see updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/3zwkA/1/)

Answer (score 2):

My personal go to "hack" for this is to use left and top to place the element and then move it correct using negative margins

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;  //move it left by half the width
```